# nRF52 Service Discovery doesn't happen on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, service-discovery, nrf52

I'm having some issues while discovering services.

It seems to connect to Android without much issue, but on iOS the connection fails. From running testing connecting it looks like the services are not discovered. I don't see any information about this problem service discovery on connection in the examples or in the documentation.
this is caused just when the developer of the gatt services gives me an update for new service so I have to put the ipad in airplane mode, is there a programmatically solution for this problem?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having problems discovering a newly added BLE service. This is most probably caused by iOS caching your device information. You should use the Service Changed Characteristic for this purpose.

According to the [Bluetooth Core specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/), Version 5.2, Vol. 3, Part G, 7 DEFINED GENERIC ATTRIBUTE PROFILE SERVICE the Service Changed characteristic is

> Mandatory if service definitions on the server can be added, changed, or removed; otherwise optional

The [Accessory Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) from Apple also states:

> The accessory shall implement the Service Changed characteristic only if the accessory has the ability
> to change its services during its lifetime.
> The device may use the Service Changed characteristic to determine if it can rely on previously read
> (cached) information from the device. See the Bluetooth 4.0 specification, Volume 3, Part G, Section
> 7.1.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I did not understand the solution what exactly should I do, clear the cache ? or what exactly ? could you give me an example please

Comment: You have to implement the "Service Changed Characteristic" on your peripheral device. What device are you using?

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand your answer, my job it's discover services and not "implement service changed" , so i enable notification if they exist and write or read what i need, I'm using core Bluetooth,I'm using iPad pro but I don't think it's a device problem

Comment: You cant solve your problem on your IPad, it has to be done on the Bluetooth device itself. Core Bluetooth saves all your device info and is not looking for new services unless the Bluetooth Device has the service I talked about. It prevents Core Bluetooth from chaching the device data. Maybe someone else has a better solution for you, this is the only one I know.

Answer (score 0):

after many days , i found the solution you should discover your peripheral like this ,

```
print("peripheral peripheral.name \(advertisementData)")
guard let nameAdvertisementData = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataLocalName"] as? String else {
        return
    }
```